# Send AVRCP commands from iOS app

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avrcp

I'm trying to build an iOS application for sending AVRCP commands via Bluetooth to a remote player.

Looking in the documentation it seems is possible to receive remote events only, not to send events to control the remote player. 
Is there any way to control the remote player via AVRCP?

Max

Comment: You can't send AVRCP Commands from iOS App.

Comment: @VineeshTP we have registered MFI program still we cannot sent AVRCP command through app ?